# Auxiliary Power Point Repair 2006 Econoline (E-150) Ford Cargo Van

Tags: fuse, fuse-panel, power-outlet

The cigarette/ power point outlet no longer works. Likely I overloaded it.

As suggested in the [manual](http://www.fordservicecontent.com/Ford_Content/catalog/owner_guides/06ecoog4e.pdf), replacing the both 20A fuses for slot 32 and 40 didn't work. All of the interior and most of the under the hood fuses have continuity.

The Haynes repair manual doesn't seem anything helpful in it beyond general info on replacing fuses

Should I remove the outlet with a removal tool, or something else I'm overlooking.

Comment: How are you testing it? I would get a multimeter onto the job or use at least 2 different devices before I'd say it wasn't working.

Comment: So what fuses don't have continuity? And, more importantly, why? How are you testing the fuses? checking for voltage or by resistance?